# Show or Hide issue in rectangle on different state in WPF Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem in Show or Hide rectangle on button click.

On Mouse Click

```
rectProjectMenu1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Again Mouse Click

```
rectProjectMenu1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

In Normal Monitor
In starting stage rectangle is display and hide on button click in my 1024*700 resolution.
When it is maximize then also show or hide on button click.

But,
In Big Size Monitor
Rectangle is display or hide on maximize state, but it not visible in normal state

My Project Window Resolution is 1024*700

Comment: What is the size of your window in `normal state`? Is it large enough?

Comment: Maybe something to do with dpp on big monitor?

Comment: App Resolution: 1024*700
First Monitor Resolution: 1366*768(Correct View)
Another Monitor Resolution: 1680*900(Incorrect View)

Comment: @WaysMeans I mean the size of your `MainWindow` (or `Form` in `winforms`) not your monitor screen.

Comment: Main Window - 1024*700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check in different monitors with debugging mode.

If you have resolution problem in this, then you can find it debugging mode in big screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have declared your `Rectangle` by drag and dropping it in Visual Studio... this leads to Visual Studio adding exact `Margin` values which are usually not wanted. Look at your `Rectangle` declaration in the XAML... try something like this instead:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Width="200" Height="100" Name="rectProjectMenu1" />
</Grid>
```

Does it still disappear? This should display the `Rectangle` in the centre of the screen regardless of the size.

Comment: No, this is not in Drag and Drop issue.